# Order of time complexity in computing $R\sin(2\alpha)$ VS $2R\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, computability, asymptotics

I was wondering, in terms of complexity and "precision", what are the differences, if any, netween the computation of

$$2R \sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha) \qquad \qquad \text{and} \qquad \qquad R\sin(2\alpha)$$

It's the same thing, for it is a goniometric identity. So are there differences in terms of order of complexity, computation time and so on?

Sorry for my ignorance in matter, hope this question is not too stupid.

Comment: The formula on the left obviously takes two function evaluations instead of one. But we don't know the time complexity as a function of the argument, so without more info we can't conclude.

Comment: Used in a mathematical context, "precision" does not make sense, the two formulas are perfectly equivalent. In a computational context, you need to specify the computational algorithms. In a programmatic context, all complexities are $O(1)$ and precision of the product might be a little lower but this is hard to say without details on the behavior of the FPU.

Comment: If you have some larger problem domain, we may be able to find the most efficient solution.  I think you have a potentially interesting problem, I just wish that there were more specifics to work with so that we could use them to our advantage.